# Subtract value of one table from another in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have the following data

```
Date    Band    Colour  Amount
02/01/2020  0-50    Red    20
01/01/2020  51-100  Blue    18
03/01/2020  51-100  Red     14
01/01/2020  51-100  Red     18
02/01/2020  51-100  Red     16
02/01/2020  51-100  Blue    14
01/01/2020  0-50    Red     12
03/01/2020  51-100  Blue    20
01/01/2020  51-100  Red     12
02/01/2020  0-50    Blue    11
02/01/2020  0-50    Red     13
01/01/2020  0-50    Red     10
02/01/2020  51-100  Blue    17
01/01/2020  51-100  Blue    17
```

I want to produce two table and filter by date.
the first table create colour by band and sum the total. same as the second table. the challenge is to find the difference between table one and table two base on filtered date

the table below show all report without filtering
[image]

when I filter table 1 to `01/01/2020`and table 2 to `02/01/2020`
my expected output will be
[image]

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: @mkRabbani How i can achieve it in power BI

Comment: You can use Metrix visual to achieve this easily. I tried with your sample data and found values showing as your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the attached .pbix file for your reference. It is difficult to explain the whole process and as a result I have attached the report file here. Check these following things from the report-

1. Two separate Date table for two different slicer
2. Created three measure
3. Interaction between Slicer and Metrix visuals.

Get the [Report File Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/106fV19HdTdS2jRZwd62ChAKyWO58B9nc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: what i want to achieve is to be able to subtract or take away the matching values in table 2 from Table 1

Comment: My expected values is the variance table

Comment: @JonWay please check the attached report file.

Comment: @JonWay nice to see it helped :)